# UIDocumentInterationController item option menu will not dismiss when click in the Navigation bar

Tags: navigationbar, dismiss, uidocumentinteraction

Title: UIDocumentInteractionController dismissing the popup when clicking anywhere in the navigation bar.

My code works find. It works well in my iPhone and iPad simulator for the most part. It does what I want., however, my issue is dismissing the default popup menu. It goes away if I click in the view area, it goes away if I pick an option in the popup, and it also goes away if I click in the tab bar area. This is good. However if I click anywhere in the navigation bar it stays put. And if I click any of the items in the navigation bar it crashes. I would like the default popup to dismiss if I click in the navigation bar as well.

**outputURLViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface outputURLViewController : UIViewController<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *previewWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *outputURLString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *outputURLName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *previewWebView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;
- (IBAction)actionButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

**outputURLViewController.m**

```
#import "outputURLViewController.h"

@interface outputURLViewController ()
{
    NSArray *myButtonArray;
    UIBarButtonItem *myActionButton;
}
@end

@implementation outputURLViewController
@synthesize outputURLString;
@synthesize outputURLName;
@synthesize previewWebView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Creates my action put and put it in the right side of navigation bar
    myActionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(actionButton:)];
    myButtonArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myActionButton, nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = myButtonArray;

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:outputURLString withExtension:@"pdf" subdirectory:@""];

    //displays my document in the webview
    [previewWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

//action that display my options in a default popup menu   
- (IBAction)actionButton:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:outputURLString withExtension:@"pdf" subdirectory:@""];
    if (url) {
        self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
        self.docController.delegate = self;
        [self.docController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:myActionButton animated:NO];
    }
}
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application{}
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application{}
//dismiss my popup menu in the view, but not the navigation bar when click
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller{}
@end
```

As you can see it very simple default popup menu code. It does what I want. I just trying to figure how to prevent it from crashing when a navigation item button is click before the popup is dismissed.

My Error that I get is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'

My DocumentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu: does work when I click in the view or any where else except the navigation bar. So is there away to prevent anyone from clicking another button in the navigation bar until the uidocumentinteractioncontroller is dismissed or have it dismiss when they tap in the navigation bar area? Or is this a normal bug that doesn't have a fix?

Comment: I found my answer for my problems. I set it up when myActionButton is clicked,it hides the back button and the action bar. And when it click out side the popup it will re-show the navigation items.

Answer (score 0):

Decide to hide the navigation items when the popup is active.

I used this code in the myActionButton section

```
if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

and this code in my documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu

```
if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myActionButton;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;

}
```